# How do you transfer weight paint or vertex colors to another model in blender?

Tags: vertex-colors, vertex-weights

I got a model then rigged it with AccuRig. When I imported the model into blender, the colors were all gone.

So I tried transferring the vertex colors. That didn't work.

Then I tried transferring the vertex weights from the new model (without colors) to the old model (with colors). That also worked, but it made the surface "crack" (the vertices became seperated, and didn't deform).

So far I've tried:

- DataTransfer Modifier
- copying attributes menu Addon

Any other ideas for what I could try?

I'm fairly new to blender, so pardon me if there's an obvious answer to my question.
[image: the model was meant for testing Accurig. I am planning to send other models through there, but if it doesn't work, i might have to look for something else]